# How do I set up the proper routes for an acts_as_commentable form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-commentable

There are two models: `User`, who does the commenting (provided by Devise), and `Audio`, which they comment on. Each `audios#show` page should list all comments for that audio, and have a little form through which to submit another one.

I made `Audio` `acts_as_commentable`. Then I made sure `Comment belongs_to :user`, and `User` `has_many :comments`.

For the routes, I have

```
resources :audios do 
  resources :comments
end
```

Then, on the audios_controller,

```
def show
  if user_signed_in?
    @comment = @audio.comments.new
  end
end
```

Then I wrote a simple `form_for(@comment)` form with a 'comment' field and a submit button. That's it.

The error I get upon loading the page is **undefined method 'comments_path'**. I googled this error, read the StackOverflow responses, and tried `form_for(@audio, @comment)` instead. This gets the error **can't write unknown attribute 'html'`.

I'm a little stumped; I've got the models and relationships sketched out on my notepad but I'm  inexperienced and the use of things that I don't fully understand, like Devise behind the scenes, is throwing me for a loop. If someone could give me a tip on these routes/forms I would love it.

Answer (score 1):

In routes.rb you need to have this:

```
# routes.rb
resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

The `:comments` route goes alone, outside from the resource you are trying to add the comment ability.

Then, if you run `rake routes` it will return:

```
$ rake routes
comments    POST        /comments(.:format)     comments#create
comment     DELETE  /comments/:id(.:format)     comments#destroy
```

This will give you the `comments_path` helper and `comment_path(:id)` helper to complete your POST and DELETE requests.

Check this tutorial, it helped me a lot when I needed to use this gem: http://twocentstudios.com/blog/2012/11/15/simple-ajax-comments-with-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
form_for [@audio, @comment]
```

or

```
form_for @comment, url: audio_comment_path(@audio, @comment)
```